# Stop execution after writing to text file with fs.writeFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify

I have the following Node.JS (ran with Express) code :

```js
let app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.get('/callback', function (req, res) {

    // your application requests refresh and access tokens
    // after checking the state parameter

    var code = req.query.code || null;

    var authOptions = {
        url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
        form: {
            code: code,
            redirect_uri: redirectUri,
            grant_type: 'authorization_code'
        },
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(clientId + ':' + clientSecret).toString('base64'))
        },
        json: true
    };

    request.post(authOptions, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

                var access_token = body.access_token,
                    refresh_token = body.refresh_token;

                fs.writeFile('test.txt', 'HELLO', function (err) {
                    if (err) return console.log(err);
                    console.log('Hello World > helloworld.txt');
                });
            }
        }
    )
});

console.log('Listening on 8888');
app.listen(8888);
```

The route is used as a callback for a request to the Spotify Web API, thus I can get an access token.

Spotify then redirects to the callback function above, you can see it in the URI by looking at "redirect_uri".

If you need more information about the Spotify Authorization Flow, see [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/).

Here's the URI I'm using to authenticate my app to Spotify.

https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8888/callback&scope=user-read-private%20user-read-email%20playlist-modify-public&state=PexBrjEzISHepTp7&show_dialog=false

*CLIENT_ID is replaced by my real CLIENT_ID in the request I make*

My problem is located to the file writing part :

```js
fs.writeFile('test.txt', 'HELLO', function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log('Hello World > helloworld.txt');
});
```

When the callback route is called by Spotify, I have the string "HELLO" wrote in my text file, so the file writing is functional.

**But even if it has finished writing the string, the Chrome page is still running and "pending" on the server. It runs for a few minutes and then crash by saying that the page didn't sent any data. Why ?**

I've looked at [this page](https://stackabuse.com/writing-to-files-in-node-js/) talking about the methods of writing to text files, using writeFile and writeFileAsync, but using both of them didn't solved my problem.

**EDIT:** I don't really want to stop the Express process! I just want to be able to process another request :)

Any idea ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you need to call res.end() when your request is complete. searching for "express end request" is a resourceful way to find the answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your get route you are not sending response, you must send response irrespective of writing a file was successful or not.

Add below code post writing to file (as well as in if error case)

res.send({YOUR_CHOICE_RESPONSE_DATA})

Comment: That was it, thank you so much :) it was so basic...

Answer (score 1):

You aren't returning anything from your route, try adding `res.send({})`